# Openfire: Save messages on server when user is offline?

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I'm writing an xmpp ios chat app which connects with an openfire server.

The app needs to be able to download all the messages that were missed by the user while the app was closed.  So I will need a way to save the missed messages sent on the server, does anyone know a good way to do this? Is there a plugin for something like this, or would this require a custom plugin or something else?

Comment: openfire automatically sends u all your offline messages when u connect back to it, u don have to do anything specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openfire, like most other XMPP servers, already stores the messages sent by users, when the receiving bare JID was offline, so that it can send those message to the client when it (re-)connects.

See also:

- [XEP-0160 - Best Practices for Handling Offline Messages](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0160.html)
- [XEP-0013 - Flexible Offline Message Retrieval](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html) (supported by Openfire)

Comment: Hey, thanks for response, can you elaborate a little more, I'm making an app which connects to an openfire server, so when I open up a connection to the server with a user's jid, it will return all the messages to me?  There's no further config or anything else necessary.

Comment: Although, it's a old post, just wnated to confirm if Openfire supports XEP-0160. I am asking because the below feature comparison chart doesn't mention Openfire supporting XEP-0160. Please confirm. Thanks.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software